# Mail layout and standards

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email

I am currently working on a ASP.NET (C#) project, where I specifically am refactoring/re-designing an implementation of auto-responses for applications and payment notifications.

As of now, the the actual body is fetched from a file written with placeholders which are formated at runtime before the mail is sent. The header and footer are hardcoded, as attempted to illustrate below.

**My main challenge is:**
To obtain a simple, clean implementation making it possible for me to create a simplistic design which can change over time.

```
l ------------------------------l  
l Header: Hard coded  
l ------------------------------l  
l Body: Fetched from file  
l ------------------------------l  
l Footer: Hard coded  
l ------------------------------l
```

**My questions are then:**
(1) What are the conventions and good practises of implementing such behavior? I'm not to concerned about the performance of a file read, but is there a better/smarter way to do this. Note that these files contain raw html with placeholders, replaced by the `string.Format(str)` method.

(2) Furthermore, I'd like to be able to implement an editing tool, for admins of the application, that could edit these body contents. I mention this due to the likely design connection with the first question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to build is a generic component of  a CMS.

How CMS works is that they uses DB to store all information, in your case its file.

So what I can suggest is use DB and import all your contents in it, Footer and Header as mentioned is hardcoded but in near future client can ask to edit it, so ideally you should store it in DB.

All your manipulation can easily work with DB.

For editor you can use FCKEditor, this editor is widely used.

thanks
Nipun

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. A sleak and dynamtic design.. Despite being rather obvious, I couldn't wrap my head around this. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielVarab Try to download source code from this and you can try your hand around it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5285/Email-Component-for-NET

Comment: This keeps gettin' better and better!